# what is the as3 bitmapdata bytearray format / how to transform into png in python

Tags: python, actionscript-3

in a local as3 application i need to capture a video at 25 frames per second and send the bytearray to a local python script.
when i try to encode the bytearray to png inside as3 it is much to slow.
so i decided to just write the raw bytearray i got from :

```
var bitmapdata:BitmapData = new BitmapData(_videow,_videoh,false,0);
bitmapdata.draw(_video);
var ba:ByteArray=bitmapdata.getPixels(bitmapdata.rect);
```

this is pretty performant and does not drop frames so far.
however, i need to convert these raw bytes to png on the python side.
any idea how i can achieve that?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's roughly the same as <s>PCX</s>* (some earlier variant of BMP). It is actually very similar to BMP, save that there are no headers, and the pixels are written from left to right, top down ARGB for transparent bitmapdata and RGB for solid.

What PNG encoder did you use? Have you tried this one: http://www.blooddy.by/en/crypto/ ? Of course, Python may be using GD / Imagemagic behind the scenes, so, obviously C code would be faster, but if you wanted it to run on the user's PC, then I'd give this a try.

PS: http://www.senocular.com/flash/actionscript/?file=ActionScript_3.0/com/senocular/images/BMPEncoder.as this may give some insights, as it is converting bitmapdata into BMP.

- Sorry, that's not a PCX, I've confused PCX to something else, it's just a variant of BMP, with a different pixel ordering.

Comment: Well, i checked. Both are still not fast enough.
Also I need transparency, so bmp is not really an option.
thanks anyway